# Loop through fields in Drupal 8

Tags: loops, drupal, twig, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I'm kind of new to Twig templating and Drupal 8 and I'm having a bit of trouble looping through some fields in a node template file. Basically, I have a Date field limited to a maximum of 2 fields, and if 2 fields are entered, I would like to display them like a date range and not just two random dates plonked on a page.

I'm trying to achieve this by using a for loop/if statement to check if more than one field exists, and display the field output accordingly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  {% set dateLength = "" %}
  {% for date in content.field_date['#items'].getValue() %}
    {% set dateLength %}
      {{ loop.length }}
    {% endset %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if dateLength == 2 %}
    {{ content.field_date['#items'].getValue()|last.value }}&mdash;{{ content.field_date['#items'].getValue()|first.value }}
  {% else %}
    {{ content.field_date['#items'].getValue() }}
  {% endif %}
```

Let me know if I'm overthinking this. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to calculate the dateLength variable with the [length twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html) as follow:

```
{% set dateLength  = content.field_date['#items'].getValue() | length %}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I'm not a Drupal expert, possibly can be also  `{% set dateLength  = content.field_date['#items'] | length %}`

Comment: Ahhh, I was definitely over complicating things. Somehow I missed the length filter when sifting through the Twig docs. Works perfectly... Thanks for your input!